# How to use "curve to mesh" Object in Boolean node?

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I use the Boolean Node in Geometry Nodes. I want to use a curve object (converted to mesh via *Curve to Mesh* node), but it doesn't work. Anyone have any idea?

Here's the [Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NzFOHVVjYarqaA1rmNy4DDkuDEpkQQys/view?usp=drive_link)

[image]

Comment: A boolean operates on [manifold](https://www.sculpteo.com/en/3d-learning-hub/create-3d-file/fix-non-manifold-geometry/) meshes.

Comment: Your link requires access. You can share your file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it and then edit your question and paste the link into it.

Comment: tbh i think it is a bug - if i exchange both entries in mesh boolean, it works, so i think it is a bug

Comment: Thank you all of you. Fixed !! Also if I put the curve and curve to mesh in same geo Node, it can be fixed as well

Answer (score 2):

The Normals of the Curve get inverted for some reason.

[image]

It seems like a bug, but to fix add a *Flip Faces* node.

[image]